# Android - TextView with different background colors

Tags: android, textview

Is it possible to have a TextView with different background colors. Eg. If the text is "This is a test", is it possible to set different background color for the four words?

Comment: You mean in the same TextView with different background colors?

Comment: can you give an example of what you mean?

Comment: yes. That is what I want to do.

Comment: You could have 4 textviews with different backgrounds and each containing a word and connect them together...

Comment: Here is an example of what I want to do...

http://tinypic.com/r/15oeyp3/8

The right hand side of the image has text with different backgrounds. The text is dynamic so I can't go with the fixed number of textviews.

Comment: Simply use SpannableString as mentioned in below ans post.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes.

```
SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(getString(R.string.hello_world));
Object greenSpan = new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.GREEN);
Object redSpan = new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.RED);
spannableString.setSpan(greenSpan, 0, 6, 0);
spannableString.setSpan(redSpan, 6, spannableString.length(), 0);

TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
textView.setText(spannableString);
```

Produces:

[image]

EDIT: There are a lot of different spannable types, you can do much nicer looking things than my basic example. Check out [this](http://flavienlaurent.com/blog/2014/01/31/spans/) article.