# Higlight Words in TextView

Tags: android

I have a `TextView` that holds a certain Text. Is it possible to change the background of each word in the `TextView` every amount of time? For example, highlight the first word then second then third and so on.

Comment: I guess you should embed html in your class file. Otherwise not possible.

Comment: can you please explain what you mean or give me a link for more info

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom TextView in android with different color words](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11479560/custom-textview-in-android-with-different-color-words)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

```
String html = "hello <font color='#ff0000'>there</font>";
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(html));
```

[More info here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml%28java.lang.String%29)

[Supported tags](http://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html)

[Mutiple background color in one TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26092216/1841194)

Comment: OP would like to change the background of the text.

Comment: can i use this to loop over the whole words?

Comment: @EugenPechanec I've added a link for adding mutiple background colors

Comment: @user1950784 Yes, it's possible

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.my_text_view);
    textView.setText("Hello there");
    mMyRunnable.start = 0;
    mMyRunnable.text = textView.getText().toString();
    mHandler = new Handler();
    mHandler.postDelayed(mMyRunnable, 1000);
}

private MyRunnable mMyRunnable = new MyRunnable();

private class MyRunnable implements Runnable{

    String text;
    int start = 0;

    @Override
    public void run () {
        //get the next index of space..notice that this answer assumes that there are no double sapces
        final int end = text.indexOf(32, start);

        Spannable wordSpan = new SpannableString(text);

        //case this is the last word
        if(end == -1){
            wordSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.CYAN), start, text.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        }
        //color the current word, set start end start handler again
        else{
            wordSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.CYAN), start, end, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            start = end + 1;
            mHandler.postDelayed(mMyRunnable, 1000);
        }

        textView.setText(wordSpan);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. It can be achieved by using [SpannableString](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html) as TextView contents. You'll have to dive into documentation to achieve exactly what you want. One of the usefull spans to use in your case is [BackgroundColorSpan](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/BackgroundColorSpan.html)